# UDP relay implementation do not work as I expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp

I am trying to implement the relay of UDP communication.

For example, I have two terminals:

- 192.168.10.5
- 192.168.10.6

I would like to monitor between the two by way of 192.168.10.3.

My environment:

```
Unity 5.1.2-f1 on MacOS X 10.8.5 using C#
```

Following is my code snippet related to the UDP communication.

```
void Monitor() {
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient (port);
        client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000; // msec
        client.Client.Blocking = false;

        while (ToggleComm.isOn) {
            try {
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);
                string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

                if (text.Length == 0) {
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                    continue;
                }
                string fromIP = anyIP.Address.ToString();
                // send to the other
                if (fromIP.Equals(ipadr1)) {
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, ipadr2, port);
                    Debug.Log("from: " + ipadr1 + " to " + ipadr2 + data);
                } else {
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, ipadr1, port);
                    Debug.Log("from: " + ipadr2 + " to " + ipadr1 + data);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err) {

            }
            // without this sleep, on android, the app will freeze at Unity splash screen
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        client.Close ();
    }
```

With the code above,

- I can send from 192.168.10.5 to 192.168.10.3
- I can send from 192.168.10.3 to 192.168.10.6 (relay)
- I can receive at 192.168.10.3 from 192.168.10.6
- I cannot receive at 192.168.10.5 from 192.168.10.3

where 192.168.10.6 works as echo server, returning received string back.

My debug print on the relay says

- from: 192.168.10.5 to 192.168.10.6
- from: 192.168.10.6 to 192.168.10.5

It seems that the relay (192.168.10.3) send to 192.168.10.5, but 192.168.10.5 cannot receive the relayed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked (not elegant yet, though).

I had misunderstanding about port of the sender and receiver.

```
void Monitor() {
    UdpClient client = new UdpClient (port);
    client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 300; // msec
    client.Client.Blocking = false;

    string fromPort = "6000"; // at first 6000 is set as dummy
    while (ToggleComm.isOn) {
        try {
            IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

            if (text.Length == 0) {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
                continue;
            }
            string fromIP = anyIP.Address.ToString();
            // send to the other
            if (fromIP.Equals(ipadr1)) {
                fromPort = anyIP.Port.ToString(); // store the port 
                client.Send(data, data.Length, ipadr2, port);
                Debug.Log("1 from: " + fromIP + "(" + fromPort
                          + ") to " + ipadr2 + "(" + port.ToString() + ")");
            } else {
                client.Send(data, data.Length, ipadr1, Convert.ToInt32(fromPort));

                Debug.Log("2 from: " + fromIP + "(" + "..." 
                          + ") to " + ipadr1 + "(" + fromPort + ")");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err) {

        }
        // without this sleep, on android, the app will freeze at Unity splash screen
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
    client.Close ();
}
```

I put the unity project at [github (v0.3)](https://github.com/yasokada/unity-150831-udpMonitor/releases/tag/v0.3)